# What is the meaning of this jQuery selection? Why we use "this" into filter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `filter()` in this way but it doesn't work :

```
$("p").filter(function(){  
    return $("span").length == 2;}).css("background-color", "yellow");});
```

If I add `this` alongside `"span"` the problem is tackled. I don't know what's the reason of being 2 element seperated with `,` into one `$` and what meaning that it has. Actually I didn't see 2 parameter together into `$` so far. Please tell me when and why I must use `this` in this example?

```
$("p").filter(function(){  
    return $("span", this).length == 2;}).css("background-color", "yellow");});
```

Comment: Jquery has [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) if you are unaware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument is the context, meaning that your selector will try to find `span` within the context, the `this` refers to the `p` itself in your case, so all the matched spans will be within the `p` context.

It seems from the code that you have more than 2 spans all through the document (global context) so when you used :

`$("span").length` in the global context it was more than 2.

But within the context of the `p`, when using `$("span", this)` you found 2 children spans.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the last declared object. In this case, refers to `$("p")`.

Comment: See here for additional info -- that second variable is called the context: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context